# bash: simple way to get list of first level folder

Tags: bash

What is the simple Unix way to get a list of first-level folders only?

```
$ mkdir -p {a,b/{b1,b2},c}
$ touch {f1.h,f2.h,a/f.h,b/b2/f2.h}
$ tree
.
├── a
│   └── f.h
├── b
│   ├── b1
│   └── b2
│       └── f2.h
├── c
├── f1.h
└── f2.h
$
```

I use

```
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort
.
./a
./b
./c
$
```

Or

```
$ ls -la |grep '^d'
drwxrwxr-x  5 user user 4096 oct.   2 05:52 .
drwxrwxrwt 14 root root 4096 oct.   2 05:45 ..
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 oct.   2 05:52 a
drwxrwxr-x  4 user user 4096 oct.   2 05:52 b
drwxrwxr-x  2 user user 4096 oct.   2 05:52 c
$
```

I’m looking for a shorter command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
$ ls -d */
a//  b//  c//
```

(I've set `alias ls='ls -F'`, hence the `//`s, `/bin/ls -d */` works nicely).